# how can redirect to another page when if statement is true in django template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a HTML page that displays some information retrieved from database, in this template i have if statement when it is return True, it must be redirect to another page,

here is my HTML Page:
**Communications.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    {% load bootstrap5 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style>
  label{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="tblToExcl" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">  
        <thead class="thead-dark">  
        <tr>  
         
          <th>Day</th>  
            <th>From</th>  
            <th>To</th>  
            <th>Name Lecturer</th>  
            <th>Lesson</th>  
            <th>Lab</th>
          
        </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
    {% for table in tables %}  
        <tr>  
           
            <td>{{ table.day }}</td>  
            <td>{{ table.strt_lec }}</td>  
            <td>{{ table.end_lec }}</td>  
            <td>{{ table.name_lecurer }}</td>
            <td>{{ table.name_lesson }}</td>  
            <td>{{ table.lab }}</td>   
           
          {% if table.comm_time_compare%}
             
             <p>time is equal</p>
           

          {% else %}   
             <p> time is not equal</p>

          {% endif %}   
        </tr>  
    {% endfor %}  
        </tbody>  
    
    </table>  
    

</body>
</html>
```

**models.py:**

```
class Communications(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    strt_lec = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    end_lec = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name_lecurer = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=LECTURER_NAME_Comm)
    name_lesson = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=LESSONS_Comm)
    lab = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LAB_NAMES_Comm)

    @property
    def comm_time_compare(self):
        current_time = time.strftime("%I:%M")
        if current_time == self.strt_lec:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('members/', views.members, name='members'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('Communications', views.show_Communications, name='Communications'),
    path('table', views.Communications_table, name='table'),
]
```

but instead the `<p>time is equal</p>` i want to direct to another page directly when the if statement is true without the user click any thing. i tried using this code:

```
{% if table.comm_time_compare%}
             <p>time is equal</p>
             <a href="{% url "table"   %}"> teble </a>
              

          {% else %}   
             <p> time is not equal</p>
```

, but it showed a link that i must click it to go to another page, while i want it go directly to another page without click anything.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to let the browser redirect through a refresh header:

```
<!-- in head -->
{% if table.comm_time_compare %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL={% url 'table' %}">
{% endif %}

<!-- in body -->
{% if table.comm_time_compare %}
    <p>time is equal</p>
    <a href="{% url 'table' %}">link</a>
{% else %}   
    <p>time is not equal</p>
{% endif %}
```

But since certain browser might ignore it, it is better to include the link in the response anyway.

Comment: how can i include it in the response please???

Comment: @RasoolALmusawie: as specified, what is not clear, you render that part in the `<head>` of the response.